# Control group selection

Tags: python, control-group

I am currently migrating some code from SAS to Python. 
I am trying to do the following in python:
I have two groups of customers: those that were exposed to a campaign, and those that were not (the ones that were not exposed is a much larger group).
I have some metrics for each customer, such as sales before the campaign started, and some segmentations.

What I need to do, is to select from the non-exposed group a control group that would be most similar to the exposed group.

Example, if in the exposed group, the average sales were $20, 20% of customers were of segment A, etc., I would like the control group to be as similar as possible to the exposed group.

Comment: You could look at using sklearn's [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) and specifying the stratified argument to match your KPIs. But I'm sure there are dedicated A/B testing frameworks in Python that might have this already baked in